# Find the product of the minimum height of defenders lower than 180 cm and the maximum height of midfielders higher than 185 cm

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```py
positions = ['GK', 'M', 'A', 'D', 'M', 'D', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'A', 'M', 'M', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'M', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'M', 'GK', 'D', 'D', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'D', 'M', 'GK', 'D', 'GK', 'D', 'D', 'M']
heights = [191, 184, 185, 180, 181, 187, 170, 179, 183, 186, 185, 170, 187, 183, 173, 188, 183, 180, 188, 175, 193, 180, 185, 170, 183, 173, 185, 185, 168, 190, 178, 185, 185, 193, 183]

np_positions = np.array(positions)
np_heights = np.array(heights)
```

My code is:

```py
print(np.min(positions=='D'[heights<180]) * np.max(positions=='A'[heights > 185]))
```

I get a TypeError. I made it another way, but I need to do this in 1 string.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is to create a 2D list with position and height using zip.

In the `min` and `max` functions of python you are able to define your own key on what the minimum and maximum value should be searched for. In this case I used a lambda function using an `if` `else` statement.

```
positions = ['GK', 'M', 'A', 'D', 'M', 'D', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'A', 'M', 'M', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'M', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'M', 'GK', 'D', 'D', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'D', 'M', 'GK', 'D', 'GK', 'D', 'D', 'M'] 
heights = [191, 184, 185, 180, 181, 187, 170, 179, 183, 186, 185, 170, 187, 183, 173, 188, 183, 180, 188, 175, 193, 180, 185, 170, 183, 173, 185, 185, 168, 190, 178, 185, 185, 193, 183]

# create a 2d array:
d = list(zip(positions, heights))
min_height_defender = min(d, key=lambda x: x[1] if x[0] == 'D' and x[1] < 180 else 1e9)
max_height_midfielder = max(d, key=lambda x: x[1] if x[0] == 'A' and x[1] > 185 else -1e9)

print( min_height_defender[1] * max_height_midfielder[1] )
>>> 33286
```

Or you can use numpy, but I would suggest that you test your minimum and maximum value *after* filtering, otherwise your code becomes unreadable:

```
# or with numpy:
positions = np.array(positions)
heights = np.array(heights)

print( heights[np.argwhere(positions == 'D')].min() * heights[np.argwhere(positions == 'A')].max() )
>>> 33286


# or without argwhere:
print( heights[positions == 'D'].min() * heights[positions == 'A'].max() )
>>> 33286
```

If you want to filter inline you can use it, but as said it is very ugly (in my opinion) and you should avoid to do more than 1 thing per line of code. But if you want of just for the kick of doing things in one line:

```
print( heights[heights<180][positions[heights<180] == 'D'].min() * heights[heights>185][positions[heights>185] == 'A'].max() )
>>> 33286
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use your numpy arrays and boolean slicing!

*NB. assuming **D**efender is **D** and **M**idfielder is **M**.*

```
            # position is D/M   condition on height
(np_heights[(np_positions=='D')&(np_heights<180)].min()
*np_heights[(np_positions=='M')&(np_heights>185)].max()
)
```

output: `33464` (178*188)